# Asp.net Report Viewer Default Printer is not selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

When I am trying to print a SSRS report from ASP.net ReportViewer, The print dialog box does not have the default printer selected in it.

I have need to set the default printer everytime before printing the report.

Please help.

Comment: Default Printer is usually your system setting. If you go on and set your default printer in windows' Device and Printer, that should do the trick.

Comment: Default Printer is already set & problem is coming from Reportviewer only, When i print a word doc or from IE (Other than report viewer) it is fine. Only in Report Viwer i always need to select.